# How to deploy Visual Studio Flask app to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using the Visual Studio 2019 **Flask Web Project** template. It runs in my local Python environment and is a good start (very much like the standard Asp.net) template. I created a Python Elastic Beanstalk Application to host this. I am attempting to deploy this on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I created a repository at: https://github.com/jlongo62/Flask-Web-Project

- I think one of these files (or a missing file) needs to be named
  application.py(it may also need some special content). I included a
  directory listing.
- It appears that I need to zip this and upload it
  through the portal/cli. I am not sure what zip should look like, but
  I suspect requirements.txt needs to be at the root.). If AWS Toolkit
  Extension cannot handle this job, it should be easy to script.
- Is there a better template or sample project in GitHub ?
- Is the fix something simple ?

```
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1.pyproj
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1.pyproj.user
    \FlaskWebProject1\requirements.txt
    \FlaskWebProject1\runserver.py
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\static
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\templates
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\views.py
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\__init__.py
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\__pycache__
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\static\content
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\static\fonts
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\static\scripts
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\static\content\bootstrap.css
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\static\content\bootstrap.min.css
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\static\content\site.css
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\static\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\static\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\static\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\static\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\static\scripts\bootstrap.js
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\static\scripts\bootstrap.min.js
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\static\scripts\jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\static\scripts\jquery-1.10.2.js
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\static\scripts\jquery-1.10.2.min.js
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\static\scripts\jquery-1.10.2.min.map
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\static\scripts\jquery.validate-vsdoc.js
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\static\scripts\jquery.validate.js
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\static\scripts\jquery.validate.min.js
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\static\scripts\jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\static\scripts\jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\static\scripts\modernizr-2.6.2.js
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\static\scripts\respond.js
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\static\scripts\respond.min.js
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\static\scripts\_references.js
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\templates\about.html
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\templates\contact.html
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\templates\index.html
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\templates\layout.html
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\__pycache__\views.cpython-37.pyc
    \FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\__pycache__\__init__.cpython-37.pyc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*With thanks to Marcin.
AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio will not support deployment or environment creation. It only applies to .Net environments.*

I have updated https://github.com/jlongo62/Flask-Web-Project to reflect these notes

1. Create AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment. Use the portal or CLI.
   *Environments > Create environment (Web server environment) > Select*

Settings:

- Platform: Python
- Platform Branch: Python 3.7
- Platform Version: 3.0.3

2. Add **application.py** with content (the port 8000 seems to be a key ingredient):

```
"""
This script runs the FlaskWebProject1 application using a development server.
"""

from os import environ
from FlaskWebProject1 import app as application

if __name__ == '__main__':
    HOST = environ.get('SERVER_HOST', 'localhost')
    try:
        PORT = int(environ.get('SERVER_PORT', '8000'))
    except ValueError:
        PORT = 8000
    application.run(HOST, PORT)
```

3. Create a zip with the following root directory. Zip file name does not matter:

```
application.py
FlaskWebProject1
requirements.txt
```

4. Deploy zip using the portal (or cli)

- Elastic Beanstalk > Environments > Flaskwebproject1-env
- click Upload and deploy

Answer (score 1):

**Your application works** on `Python 3.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.0.3` EB environment.

Just change `runserver.py` into `application.py`. Also you can slightly modify (port and name) its content, unless you want to customize EB environment to match your application' settings.

*application.py*

```
"""
This script runs the FlaskWebProject1 application using a development server.
"""

from os import environ
from FlaskWebProject1 import app as application

if __name__ == '__main__':
    HOST = environ.get('SERVER_HOST', 'localhost')
    try:
        PORT = int(environ.get('SERVER_PORT', '8000'))
    except ValueError:
        PORT = 8000
    application.run(HOST, PORT)
```

Zip it into `app.zip` (example name) with content:

```
application.py
FlaskWebProject1
requirements.txt
```

Deploy the `app.zip`.