# Cannot deploy flask application built by visual studio 2019 to Beanstalk with nginx

Tags: nginx, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to flask and beanstalk. What I am trying to do right now is create a simple flask application and deploy it to Beanstalk. I haven't made any changes to my codes which auto-generated from the VS 2019 except renaming my runserver.py to application.py

I tried to deploy my code by following instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63083403/how-to-deploy-visual-studio-flask-app-to-elastic-beanstalk) but I keep getting this error in nginx log, even with curl localhost

`*5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "xxxxx.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"`

Please help.